# Can i access modifed properties mulltiple jvms?

Tags: java, properties

I have defined the properties using `System.setProperty("","")` .This properties can access other JVMs also.Those properties where did stored in JVM?.

Answer (score 0):

A system property is kept in memory, in the JVM executing the program where `System.setProperty` is called. JVM A won't see the value of a property set in JVM B. If you want to make JVM A aware of a property change in JVM B, then you need to make the two JVMs communicate with each other.

Knowing what you want to do with these system properties and these multiple JVMs might help giving you a better answer.